# Converting from partial derivatives of $f(r)$ in $x, y, z$ to dot-product of vectors

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

This is from my mathematical physics book. I don't know how the right side arrived from the left side of the equation: 
$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{df}{dr}\vec r \cdot\nabla r$$

Note that $f$ is a function of $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ alone: $f(r)$.

Comment: If $f$ is a function of $r$ alone, why do you have partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$ in your expression?

Comment: @smcc Because $r$ in turn is a function of $x$, $y$, and $z$

Comment: Yes I understand that, but it is really an abuse of notation because it is using $f$ to refer to two distinct functions: $f$ as a function of one variable and the function formed by composing $f$ with the function defined by $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. (Actually I was still editing my comment when the question was deleted.)

Comment: @smcc Fighting abuse of notation is a losing battle. In physics, this notation is pretty common

Comment: Yes, I know it is quite a common notation. I sometimes use it myself when teaching the chain rule to students. (But I stress that it is an abuse of notation while doing so!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$$

by the chain rule. Since $f$ is just a function of $r$, $\partial f/\partial r = df/dr$. Using analogous results for y and z,

$$x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + z \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{df}{dr} (\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} x + \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} y + \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} z)$$

Since $\vec{r} = (x,y,z)$ and $\nabla r = (\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial r}{\partial z})$, this can be written more compactly as

$$ x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + z \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{df}{dr} (\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} x + \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} y + \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} z) = \frac{df}{dr} \vec{r} \cdot \nabla r$$